# In Bash, how to typeset a variable (numeric) to 5digit?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

how shall I typeset a variable in bash, so it always pads with leadding zeros, if number is smaller.
For Eg. 
If I typeset a variable 'a' as 5 digit and give value 78, output should be 00078

There are various answeres already available, which tell how to do it, like using 
`printf -v a "%05d" 78;`
etc, but please note if we do this way we change the output just once. 

Eg. 
`printf -v a "%05d" 78
echo $a
a=32
echo $a;`

Output:
00078
32            No padding here

in ksh, there is option called typeset and used like this
`typeset -Z5 gen=78;
echo $gen;
gen=32;
echo $gen;`

Output:
00072
00032

However for bash -Z, option is not available for typeset. 
One answer, on a forum, claimed to use "declare" instead "typeset" in bash, however -Z option of ksh, typeset is not available even in declare.
**Question**
Is there any feasible solution to this, like I set the atttribute of variable once. Or do I need to tweek my output everytime (like using printf).

Comment: AFAIK this is `ksh` specific. So, if you need this, use `ksh`. Alternatively, you can define a function like `pad() { printf "%05d" $1; }` or such...

Answer (score 2):

You might do

```
a=78
astr=$(printf "%05d" a)
echo $astr
```

Comment: did you read the question in detail or just replied reading the question headline??

Comment: Basile read it and provided your answer which by negative-implication tells you that you need to tweek the output each time. (just assign the padded copy to a new variable (or to the same variable if you don't need the original unpadded form) which is then persistent throughout the remainder of the script). E.g. `a=78; a=(printf "%05d" a);` to pad a=00078. If you need to keep `a` unchanged, then `b=(printf "%05d" a)`. There `a=78`; `b=00078`. No tricks.